# Permanent of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, permanent

I'm working through the Doubly Stochastic Matrices section of Linear Algebra in Action for a project and am a bit stuck on Exercise 23.18. The problem goes as follows.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} B&0\\C&D\end{bmatrix}$ where $B$ and $D$ are square matrices. Show that $$per(A)=per(B)\cdot per(D).$$ I've convinced myself it should be true by working through a few examples but I'm not sure how to prove it. It shouldn't be too hard but I cant for the life of me figure it out. Maybe it's because I am up far too late. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Its similar to the determinant, but all terms have positive sign.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Okay, thanks! I think that was enough of a hint that I should be able to get something written up. If I get stuck again ill come back. I'm fairly rusty in my proof-writing so you may be hearing from me again soon. Thanks again.

Comment: @Wuestenfux So i just went about decomposing $A$ into $\begin{bmatrix}B&0\\0&D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\D^{-1}C&I\end{bmatrix}$ But why do we know that $D$ is invertible?